# understanding proper python code organization

Tags: python, class, image-processing

Well i am planning on making image processing program using python language. I am still very new to python so i have not yet looked into the various image libraries available. (i will plan to do so later) but at the moment i am most confused on what is the proper layout of how python code should be written. From what i picked up from some of the tutorials i saw it seems that classes are available for python. I am used to programing in c#, c++, java and i was planning on setting up my code in in following manner:

classes: readingWritingImg, canny, laplacian, main

where each class would have several methods and several of the important methods would be run in the main class

I am planning on writing each of these classes in a separate .py files and using import in the main class to run them. This is pretty standard programingesq in the programing that i am used to but i feel like i am making a big mistake by doing this in python. Is it better standard to write everything in functions without class usage? Is it normal to separate different classes by writing them on separate .py files rather the same .py file? A problem i can forsee is that for canny, readingWritingImg, laplacian class i may import some of the same libraries from img proc library available and i would be getting data from one class passing it to another and then passing it back to the first class to write. I am unsure if something like this would be standard practice.

Perhaps it may be best where i just write everything in the same .py file with no classes so everything is directly visible to everyone wit global like varaibles?

Also i have read a short article stating that getters and setters are no good in python and should not be done on a article titled: "python is not java". This was some what confusing to me since a short power point tutorial i saw on class usage in python used a getter as in part of the example. (used _ *init* _ as well which seemed like a constructor for python)

I have looked through some tutorials but does not do a good job mentioning what is best. Any links that may push me in the right direction for what i am looking for is greatly appreciated.

Comment: thxs the link seems helpful. I didn't really see this thread while i was searching

Comment: If you have other questions that aren't answered there, feel free to ask them here :)

Comment: well from what i see, it seems that i should divided by module but can this module they speak of be class or function? (my assumption is that it would generally be a function) And is it common to have  project just run in a single .py file? I felt like there wasn't much detail on if i should write different functions (functions that are not very related) on separate .py files and import

Comment: A module is not a class nor a function, it's a single .py file.A module can contain function definitions and class definitions, as well as any other code (which will get run when the module is imported)